# Broken/Invalid image links

Tags: bug, mobile-web, images

Today, I uploaded this [image](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/295/cqa.png) on a [question](https://superuser.com/q/613042/30791) I asked on superuser.com. But strangely enough, on my computer the image which is shown on the question is valid but if I look at the same question via mobile site of superuser then I see this [image](http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/9940/3ne1.jpg). which is invalid. I don't know if the other users who are reporting that the image is invalid are on a mobile device.

And here's the original link to the image uploaded: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhsnS.png

It seems to be some kind of bug which is displaying the invalid image on the same link to some users. I doubt that it could be that the image format (.png) I used is unsupported.